# Calculating probability distribution from time series data in python

Tags: python, scipy

I have a question about probability distribution function I have a time series data and I want to calculate the probability distribution of data in different time windows.

I have developed the following code but i could not find the value of probability distribution for this function.

```
a = pd.DataFrame([0.0,
21.660332407421638,
20.56428943581567,
20.597329924045983,
19.313207915827956,
19.104973174542806,
18.031361568112377,
17.904747973652125,
16.705687654209264,
16.534206966165637,
16.347782724271802,
13.994284547628721,
12.870120434556945,
12.794530081249571,
10.660675400742669])
```

this is the histogram and density plot of my data:

```
a.plot.hist()
a.plot.density()
```

but i don't know how can I calculate the value of the area under density curve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can directly call the method `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` which is also used by pandas internally.
This method returns the desired function.
You can then call one of the methods from `scipy.integrate` to calculate areas under the kernel density estimate, e.g.

```
from scipy import stats, integrate

kde = stats.gaussian_kde(a[0])

# Calculate the integral of the kde between 10 and 20:
xmin, xmax = 10, 20
integral, err = integrate.quad(kde, xmin, xmax)

x = np.linspace(-5,20,100)
x_integral = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)

plt.plot(x, kde(x), label="KDE")
plt.fill_between(x_integral, 0, kde(x_integral),
                 alpha=0.3, color='b', label="Area: {:.3f}".format(integral))
plt.legend()
```

[image]