# How can I generate random time series data for a given probability distribution of wind speed and wind angles?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, montecarlo, probability-density

I have imported an excel data of ship operations into a Pandas data frame. The data frame has latitude and longitude and time stamps with an interval of 20 min. The data is for a voyage of one month. I also have the true wind speed and wind angle probability distribution.

Is it possible to generate a random time series of wind speed and wind angles to fit into my already existing Pandas data frame? The condition is that:

1. The time series should be approximately be same as my given probability of occurance.
2. Even though its random the wind speeds and angles should not change drastically. At one time stamp we have 10 knots wind speed and another one its 50 knots. That is not realistic.

The distribution of wind speeds is like this.

[image: True wind speed and direction distribution]

Finally, the idea is to able to carry out a simulation performing the same random generation mentioned above for n number of times to calculate the shaft power. This would be something like a monte carlo simulation. Need some guidance for this too.

Can you please give me some ideas and modules or functions in Python using Pandas that I would be able to do this? I can then dig deeper into those to study and complete this. I have added the .csv file with the time stamps and ship speeds.

[.csv file with time stamps, latitude and longitude and ship speed](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10vYGkS9Fq3SD_YvR7tNrkjfxKlUjwLyR?usp=sharing)

Comment: As a starting point: to produce those plots, do you already have data for a distribution?  If so, you could look at [this question, and the accepted answer][1]  As this suggests, you can produce random data following a distribution using [scipy.stats][2].

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49293019/calculating-probability-distribution-from-time-series-data-in-python
  [2]: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/stats.html

Comment: Sounds like a job for the [Metropolis Hastings Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm)

Comment: @SRawson Thank you for the comment. I actually want to generate the time series from a plot like in the question. I have managed to plot these from a time series already. It is the other way around that I am looking for.

Comment: So you want to find a method to convert an image of a distribution/histogram plot to data you can then use to model a distribution?  I'm not sure this is possible.

Comment: Yes sort of. Yes I thought so too. I am trying to do this a bit different now. Thanks for your comment. :)